# Trying to display previous visit date against each record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a set of visit records that I am trying work out some additional information based on the same data set:

[image: data table]

I am trying to add a column on each row that gives the date previous to the current record based on the Actual Date so the second row would report the first rows actual date, the third the second etc... I would expect the first to report NULL

I have already created columns for First Visit and Last Visit using the following SQL

```
(SELECT TOP 1 v2.ACTUALDATE 
from VISITS v2 
   LEFT JOIN TRVISIT tv2 ON v2.VISID = tv2.VISID 
WHERE tv2.TRAINEEID = trv.TRAINEEID 
ORDER BY v2.ACTUALDATE) as FirstVisit,

(SELECT TOP 1 v2.ACTUALDATE 
 from VISITS v2 
   LEFT JOIN TRVISIT tv2 ON v2.VISID = tv2.VISID 
 WHERE tv2.TRAINEEID = trv.TRAINEEID 
 ORDER BY v2.ACTUALDATE DESC) as LASTVisit,
```

EDIT* This is using MS SQL Server 2012, there are two tables involved in generating the data

Table 1 TRVISIT contains the following:
TRAINEEID, VISID

Table 2 VISITS contains the following:
VISID, VISITTYPE, PLANDATE, PLANEDNDATE, ACTUALDATE, ACTUALENDDATE, NOTES

I am trying to create a view that allows me to report for each TRAINEEID a list of visits with the individual data for each visit plus additional columns:
-VisitCount a count of visits for each Trainee
-ReviewCount a count of specific Visit type for each Trainee
-FirstVisit the date the first visit happened
-Lastvisit the date the last visit happened
-Previous Visit the date of the visit happened prior to the visit in the current record.

FULL CODE:

```
SELECT 

--Link Data
trv.TRAINEEID,

--Visit Data
trv.VISID,
v.VISITTYPE,
v.PLANDATE,
v.PLANENDDATE,
v.ACTUALDATE,
v.ACTUALENDDATE,

v.NOTES,

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TRVISIT t2 WHERE t2.TRAINEEID = trv.TRAINEEID) AS VisitCount,
(SELECT COUNT(case WHEN v2.VISITTYPE = 'R' then 1 else null end) FROM TRVISIT tv2 LEFT JOIN VISITS v2 ON tv2.VISID = v2.VISID WHERE tv2.TRAINEEID = trv.TRAINEEID) AS ReviewCount,
(SELECT TOP 1 v2.ACTUALDATE from VISITS v2 LEFT JOIN TRVISIT tv2 ON v2.VISID = tv2.VISID WHERE tv2.TRAINEEID = trv.TRAINEEID ORDER BY v2.ACTUALDATE) as FirstVisit,
(SELECT TOP 1 v2.ACTUALDATE from VISITS v2 LEFT JOIN TRVISIT tv2 ON v2.VISID = tv2.VISID WHERE tv2.TRAINEEID = trv.TRAINEEID ORDER BY v2.ACTUALDATE DESC) as LASTVisit,
(SELECT LAG(v2.ACTUALDATE, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY tv2.TRAINEEID ORDER BY v2.ACTUALDATE ASC) from VISITS v2 LEFT JOIN TRVISIT tv2 ON v2.VISID = tv2.VISID WHERE tv2.TRAINEEID = trv.TRAINEEID) as PrevVist,

COUNT(*) OVER () as Total_Rows

FROM TRVISIT trv
LEFT JOIN VISITS v on trv.VISID = v.VISID

ORDER BY v.ACTUALDATE
```

Comment: It is not clear why you are joining two tables when you only mention one data table.  If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, then use the `LAG` analytic function.

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole bunch of [window functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) that use the over clause, not limited to just the `lag` function. You can leverage those instead of resorting to multiple subqueries for each aggregation that you want.

The below answer should get you everything you're looking for.

```
select tv.traineeid
, v.plandate
, v.planenddate
, v.actualdate
, v.actualenddate
, count(v.visid) over (partition by tv.traineeid) as VisitCount
, sum(case when tv.visittype = 'R' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by tv.traineeid) as ReviewCount
, min(v.actualdate) over (partition by tv.traineeid) as FirstVisit
, max(v.actualdate) over (partition by tv.traineeid) as LastVisit
, lag(v.actualdate, 1, NULL) over (partition by tv.traineeid order by v.actualdate asc) as PrevVisit
from trvisit as tv
left join visits as v on tv.visid = v.visid
```